# Ich lege Wert auf Umweltschutz. Ich lege Wert auf Bildungspolitik

Tags: sentence-structure

If we want to connect these 2 sentences by "sowohl ... als auch" ! Where would be the position of the word "Wert" in the new sentence? in other words: which is more grammatically correct: Ich lege sowohl auf Umweltschutz als auf Bildungspolitik Wert OR Ich lege sowohl Wert auf Umweltschutz als auf Bildungspolitik.

Comment: You have forgotten the *auch*, apart from that both are ok.

Answer (score 5):

It's a matter of focus. The front and end of the sentence get more emphasis than the middle part.

> Ich lege sowohl auf Umweltschutz als **auch** auf Bildungspolitik Wert.
>
> Ich lege sowohl Wert auf Umweltschutz als **auch** auf Bildungspolitik.

Both are roughly equivalent and you will hear both. The sentence with *Wert* at the end puts a bit of emphasis on it.

> Sowohl auf Umweltschutz als **auch** auf Bildungspolitik lege ich Wert.

is also also common to put additional emphasis on the two topics instead of *ich*. So there's no rule or even good pratice not to separate *Wert auf*.

Answer (score 3):

The best way of formulating the sentence is "Ich lege sowohl Wert auf Umweltschutz als auch auf Bildungspolitik.", as the phrase part "Wert auf" should not be separated, unless you wish to make a specific point.

Comment: Bei _sowohl X als auch Y_ sollten X und Y von derselben Art sein. “Ich lege sowohl Wert als auch Eier“ wäre korrekt, denn Wert und Eier sind zwei Substantive. “Ich lege sowohl Wert ... als auch auf ...“ geht jedoch nicht. Es sollte “Ich lege Wert sowohl auf ... als auch auf ...“ oder “Ich lege sowohl auf ... als auch auf ... Wert“ heißen.

Answer (score 0):

In the version, "Ich lege sowohl auf Umweltschutz als auch auf Bildungspolitik *Wert*", you are giving emphasis to the word Wert. That's why I put it in italics, to show what you are really doing. (As Janka pointed out, the emphasis in a sentence is on words at the end, or beginning.)

The more "normal" construction is "Ich lege sowohl Wert auf Umweltschutz als auch auf Bildungspolitik," (Alex's point). That has no special emphasis on the word Wert, and the sentence flows more smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that *lege Wert* is not separated in the original sentences

> [Ich lege Wert] [auf Umweltschutz].
>
> [Ich lege Wert] [auf Bildungspolitik].

Therefore, I would not separate *lege Wert* in the combination

> [Ich lege Wert] sowohl [auf Umweltschutz] als auch [auf Bildungspolitik].

If you, however, decide to separate, then *Wert* should go at the end:

> [Ich lege <s>Wert</s>] sowohl [auf Umweltschutz] als auch [auf Bildungspolitik] Wert.

Aside from that, I would prefer the conjunction *und*:

> [Ich lege Wert] [auf Umweltschutz] und [<s>auf</s> Bildungspolitik].